# Wrong Path for JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift

hello i want to print the team name with Json and Swift but the path starts with a zero. The correct path is 0.team_name .

In other apps i would normally use print(decodedData.team_name) and it would print it. Or if it would contain arrays I would use print(decodedData.team_name[0]).

But the Json starts with 0. What can I do? print(decodedData.0.team_name) doesnt work it says Value of type 'WeatherData' has no member '0'. decodedData.[0].team_name also doesnt work.

This is my Swift Code:

```
func parseJSON(weatherData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
        print(decodedData.0.team_name)
       } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Here the json:
[image]

```
[{"team_key": "2611", "team_name": "Leicester", "team_badge": "https://apiv2.apifootball.com/badges/2611_leicester.png", "players": [24 items], "coaches": [1 item] },
```

Comment: You have an error thrown, no? Show full error, but I'd guess `try decoder.decode([WeatherData].self, from: weatherData)` should do the trick, but without your model and the full error message, that's asking my cristal ball.

Comment: The error is that is says WeatherData has no member 0. This is my WeatherData: ---> struct WeatherData: Decodable{
    let team_name: String
    
}

Comment: Remove first ` print(decodedData.0.team_name)`, then run, and `print(error)`  should be called. But my suggestion code should work.

Comment: I already solved it with the code from the other person. It looks like I only had to change a little thing.
But thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode it as an array of `WeatherData`. Replace:

```
let decodedData =  try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
print(decodedData.0.team_name)
```

With:

```
let decodedData =  try decoder.decode([WeatherData].self, from: weatherData)
print(decodedData[0].team_name)
```

Comment: Ohh ok now it works. I tried using the 0 with an Array but it looks like i have to do the same with WeatherData too. Thank you very much!